# Linux vlan bridge not working

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vlan, bridge

I try to made vlan-bridge on ubuntu 10.4, because I like to run ebtables on every vlan ports.

I create a script to make this job easier:

```
    $DEV  ="lan.180"   # vlan
    $VDEV ="brlan180"  # vlan-bridge
    $IP   ="192.168.10.1" 
    $MASK ="255.255.255.0"

    ifconfig $DEV 0.0.0.0

    brctl addbr $VDEV
    brctl addif $VDEV $DEV

    ifconfig $DEV 0.0.0.0
    ifconfig $VDEV $IP netmask $MASK
    ifconfig $VDEV up
```

after i execute the script, brctl show the brigde

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
brlan180        8000.0026b9847***       no              lan.180
```

and dmesg show the state of the bridge

```
[356192.560351] vlan180: port 1(lan.180) entering learning state
[356203.504216] vlan180: no IPv6 routers present
[356207.537207] vlan180: port 1(lan.180) entering forwarding state
```

But, there is no response when I ping the member of the network

```
From 192.168.114.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.114.1 icmp_seq=460 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The iptables is accepting all input, accepting all forward, and i got net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in sysctl

- What did I missed?
- Should vlan port being up first or bridge first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you see if the $DEV is actually up? I'm not sure bringing the bridge up brings up the members.

```
ifconfig $DEV up 0.0.0.0
```

instead of 
    ifconfig $DEV 0.0.0.0

Are you sure the vlan tags are accepted by the network? Does it work without bridging?

Also, iptables and ip_forward are the layer above, bridging is happening at layer 2 so it shouldn't influence bridging.

Comment: Thank's. ifconfig $DEV up 0.0.0.0 really do the magic. The reason i turn the vlan to vlan-bridge because I want to had layer2 filters. Vlan tags are works on my network, I need the bridge just for precautions.